# Rename [revolution-r] to [microsoft-r]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[Revolution Analytics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com) was [acquired by Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/04/06/microsoft-closes-acquisition-of-revolution-analytics/) at the beginning of 2015, and the Revo brand has been pretty much retired at this point. There were a few stragglers, but the products once known as Revolution R are now universally called Microsoft R. Thus I'd like to request that the [revolution-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revolution-r) tag should be changed to [microsoft-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-r).

Comment: A synonym is the proper solution.  Also keeps users that have an older version or completely don't care who owns the product happy.

Comment: An existing question will have to be retagged first then, preferably a good question that doesn't risk being closed/deleted.

Comment: A synonym is definitely needed, but the primary tag should be Microsoft, not Revolution. I doubt the Revo brand is coming back....

Comment: I don't really think it's an issue. The newer folks that use it will be using the newer tag and I suspect any older issues will be irrelevant. Perhaps get Microsoft to sponsor the `microsoft-r` tag as well since they're making a ton of $ off of an open source project and getting quite a bit of free help for it here on SO.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments, the appropriate procedure is to tag questions with the new [microsoft-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-r) tag.

I have started this process and have tagged ~10 questions with the new tag.

Comment: I've created a synonym of revolution-r to microsoft-r - that'll save bumping posts that don't otherwise require editing...